# Using css 'important' in both the media query cases

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am creating a mobile application in which I am getting some error.

here my core style is for desktop:

```
.abc{
     width:1001px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
.abc{
     width:320px!important;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
.abc{
     width:480px!important;
}
}
```

Here from the above styles only the style of 480px is applying for both the 320px and 480px.

Is there any alternate suggestion to come over this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set a min-width

```css
.abc {
    width: 1001px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .abc {
        width: 320px;
    }
}

/* set a min-width here, so these rules don't apply for screens smaller than 321px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    .abc{
        width: 480px;
    }
}
```

If I'm right you should be able to remove the `!important` syntax too...

Comment: Thanks I hope it will work, in browser mode its working, hope too it will works on mobile too....

Answer (score 5):

This is because `max-width:480px;` still targets 320px too. Change the last one to:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px)  and (max-width: 480px) {
    .abc {
        width: 480px !important;
    }
}
```

and this will stop that query affecting anything below 321px.

It doesn't look like you need `!important` This fix has nothing to do with that so I would remove that if I were you, it may mess things up in the future

An alternative solution would be to move the 320px query below the 480px. They both have the same specificity so the one that comes last in the cascade would take precedence.

Comment: That's a better solution IMO, not worse. If you're going to use the cascade, feel free to use it properly. Also remove the `!important`s - they don't need to be there regardless of which solution you choose.

Comment: @BoltClock Added about `!important` just before you commented :) Also removed "though worse,"